# Synonymize [di2] and [shimano-di2]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Combine the tags for [di2](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/di2) and [shimano-di2](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shimano-di2). There's no need for both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest merging [di2](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/di2) (24 questions) into [shimano-di2](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shimano-di2) (36 questions) since the latter is more descriptive, and will show up in the tag search box when people start typing either "Shimano" or "Di2."

Comment: I also wrote up a quickie tag wiki for [tag:shimano-di2] since it didn't have any, and I'd hate that work to go to waste. :D

Answer (score 2):

Done.

```
Merge results
updating post history, 25 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 24 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 15 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'di2': [di2] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 53
tag remapping of [shimano-di2] and [di2] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
2 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!

Tag Synonym di2 -> shimano-di2 was approved!
```